# How to fully backup a WordPress site?

Tags: backup

I want to take a full backup of a WordPress website regularly (manual or automatic), including files, database, etc. how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To backup WordPress website (on your own host), you have 2 options.

**Option 1**

Use a plugin such as [BackUpWordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/backupwordpress/).

**Option 2**

Backup database and your contents individually.

- To backup your database, you will have to sign in to your
  cPanel/DirectAdmin area and head over to database section of the
  panel. There, you can select your database and make a backup of it,
  saving it on a safe place for further use.
- To backup your content, head over the the file manager section of your cPanel/DirectAdmin area, select and backup the `wp-content` folder. You can also download it and save it.

Remember, you will also need to have a backup of your `wp-config.php` file, existing in the WordPress's root folder. If you want it to be more safe, you can backup the entire WordPress's folder.